# Method to calculate an amount after one deposit

Tags: javascript

I have an object named `bank`, when the user deposits for example `50` euros, tha balance is always of `0`. Sincerely, I don't see why? My method `deposit()` isn't correct?

```
var bank = {
    name : "Depuis",
    firstname : "Denis",
    accountNumber : "BE42-1525899822",
    email : "depuis.denisf@gmail.com",
    phone : "010.49.48.00",
    balance : 0.0
};


deposit(50);
console.log("Balance is of => " + bank.balance);

function deposit(amount){
    if(amount > 0){
        this.balance += amount;
        console.log("The amount is of " + amount + " euros.");
    }
}
```

Comment: `this` won't be what you think it is. It will likely be the window object

Comment: Try `deposit.apply(bank, 50);` instead of `deposit(50);`

Comment: `deposit.call(bank, 50)`. You need to provide correct context to your deposit function
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Comment: @Wazeed: Thank you for your help, it's works with `deposit.call(bank, 50)`

Comment: @Oleksandr Sakun: thank you a lot, I did not know...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` inside the deposit function does not refer to the `bank` object, it refers to the `window` object, and this is because of the way the function is being called.

You can add a method inside the bank object which can call the `deposit` function which will make `this` refer to the bank object.

`this` is set based on the context. In the snippet below, the `deposit` function is being called in a similar manner but from a different context which sets `this` differently.

You should read more about how `this` works as mentioned in the comments.

```js
var bank = {
    name : "Depuis",
    firstname : "Denis",
    accountNumber : "BE42-1525899822",
    email : "depuis.denisf@gmail.com",
    phone : "010.49.48.00",
    balance : 0.0,
    depositAmt: function(amount) {
      deposit(amount)
    }
};

bank.depositAmt(50);
console.log("Balance is of => " + bank.balance);

function deposit(amount){
    if(amount > 0){
        // this now refers to the bank object
        this.balance += amount;
        console.log("The amount is of " + amount + " euros.");
    }
}
```

Or you can directly refer to the `bank` object.

```js
var bank = {
    name : "Depuis",
    firstname : "Denis",
    accountNumber : "BE42-1525899822",
    email : "depuis.denisf@gmail.com",
    phone : "010.49.48.00",
    balance : 0.0
};


deposit(50);
console.log("Balance is of => " + bank.balance);

function deposit(amount){
    if(amount > 0){
        // this here does not refer to that 
        // it refers to the window
        bank.balance += amount;
        console.log("The amount is of " + amount + " euros.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should consider how use the *this* operator. In this website you can search for more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

See the next sample:

```
const test = {
  prop: 42,
  func: function() {
    return this.prop;
  },
};

console.log(test.func());
// expected output: 42
```

In this sample of code is used the function keyword so the this keyword can be used to access to the object fields. You should consider that each function called inside it can use the this operator to get the same object reference.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the function and set the context to the `bank`.

```js
const bank = {
  name: "Depuis",
  firstname: "Denis",
  accountNumber: "BE42-1525899822",
  email: "depuis.denisf@gmail.com",
  phone: "010.49.48.00",
  balance: 0.0
};

deposit.call(bank, 50); // Call with context of the bank.
console.log(`Current balance: ${bank.balance} euros`);

function deposit(amount) {
  if (amount > 0) {
    this.balance += amount;
    console.log(`The amount is of ${amount} euros.`);
  }
}
```

A better alternative would be to use OOP and create a `Bank` object that can access and modify account balances.

```js
const main = () => {
  const bank = new Bank({ currencyType: '€' });
  const customer = bank.createCustomer({
    givenName: "Denis",
    surname: "Depuis",
    email: "depuis.denisf@gmail.com",
    phone: "010.49.48.00"
  });
  const { accountNumber } = customer;

  console.log(customer.greeting());
  bank.deposit(accountNumber, 50.25);
  bank.withdraw(accountNumber, 20.10);
};

const defaultCustomerProperties = {
  givenName: '',
  surname: '',
  email: '',
  phone: '',
  balance: 0.00
};

class Customer {
  constructor(options) {
    const opts = { ...defaultCustomerProperties, ...options };
    this.accountNumber = opts.accountNumber;
    this.givenName = opts.givenName;
    this.surname = opts.surname;
    this.email = opts.email;
    this.phone = opts.phone;
    this.balance = opts.balance;
  }
  greeting() {
    return `Welcome ${this.givenName}! (${this.accountNumber})`;
  }
}

class Bank {
  constructor(options = {}) {
    this.currencyType = options.currencyType || '$';
    this.customers = {};
  }
  createCustomer(options) {
    const accountNumber = `BExx-xxxxxxxxxx`.replace(/x/g, g => Math.floor(Math.random() * 10));
    const account = new Customer({ ...options, accountNumber });
    this.customers[accountNumber] = account;
    return account;
  }
  findCustomer(accountId) {
    const customer = this.customers[accountId];
    if (customer == null) {
      throw new Error(`Account by [id=${accountId}] not found!`);
    }
    return customer;
  }
  deposit(accountId, amount) {
    const customer = this.findCustomer(accountId);
    customer.balance += amount;
    console.log(`Deposited ${this.formatCurrency(amount)} into ${accountId}. New balance: ${this.formatCurrency(customer.balance)}`);
  }
  withdraw(accountId, amount) {
    const customer = this.findCustomer(accountId);
    if (customer.balance < amount) {
      throw new Error(`Customer balance is less than the desired amount!`);
    }
    customer.balance -= amount;
    console.log(`Withdrew ${this.formatCurrency(amount)} from ${accountId}. New balance: ${this.formatCurrency(customer.balance)}`);
  }
  formatCurrency(amount) {
    return `${this.currencyType}${amount.toFixed(2)}`;
  }
  retrieveBalance(accountId) {
    const customer = this.findCustomer(accountId);
    return customer.balance;
  }
};

main();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```